# Rails3 Site Root redirection and Devise - can I capture the initial URL query string before redirection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, routes, devise

In my routes.rb file I have my root set like this:

```
root :to => "portal#index"
```

In the portal controller, Devise steps in to authenticate the user

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

and redirects users to /users/sign_in

All that works fine...

I'm seeing a lot of intrusion attempts in my logs that have this type of url

```
example.com/?gclid=CPTKkZqfu6kCFVOFzAodLUa9-Q
```

I want to log visitors to the site *WITHIN* the Rails app and I want to use this string to distinguish real visitors from intrusion attempts

But I lose that query string through the redirection to /users/sign_in...

Is there any way to capture that initial query string within the Rails app, other than in the web server logs?

One thought...I am using Rails3 so I'm using Rack under the hood - might I have access to the string through Rack?

thanks

**Here is my answer to my own question - StackOverflow won't let me post an answer for 8 hours ?!?!? but I can edit my original question... sigh**

In my application_controller I've added this method which stores the current request.url and the previous one in the session

```
def store_request_url_in_session
  session['request_url_prev'] = session['request_url']
  session['request_url'] = request.url
end
```

I then call that *before* my authentication call

```
before_filter :store_request_url_in_session
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Now, that gets called on *every* action, but it is simply assigning two strings

In my sessions_controller (subclassed from the default devise controller) I add this filter

```
before_filter :log_http_request
```

which is what writes a log record only when the current action is 'sign_in'

```
def log_http_request
  if request.url =~ /sign_in/
    logger.info("**** #{request.remote_ip} | #{session['request_url']} | #{session['request_url_prev']} ")
  end
  session.delete('request_url')
end
```

It's not elegant but it gets me what I need right now. So an intrusion attempt like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/?gclid=CPTKkZqfu6kCFVOFzAodLUa9-Q
```

is logged as

```
**** 127.0.0.1 | http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in | http://localhost:3000/?gclid=CPTKkZqfu6kCFVOFzAodLUa9-Q
```

Cleaner solutions are welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to capture it in a session variable using

```
session[:referer] ||= request.referer
```

I'm no so familiar with devise so can't say for sure. Just put this in your index action in the portal controller.

Comment: That doesn't work as Devise redirects to 'sign_in' before portal#index  gets run - but I think I have a solution - will post momentarily...

Comment: Turns out I can't answer my own question for 8 hours... don't have a high enough reputation - and comments don't use the same formatting as regular answers - StackOverflow is great in some respects and a major pain in others...